# django save override question

Tags: django

I have a field in models that has primary_key=True. Now I want to override the save method and check if the object is created. How can I check it if I can't check self.id?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check self.pk instead of self.id

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut

Comment: I have always self.pk, even if the object was just created

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the save method? Depending on what you want to do you could query the db for your new pk value and check if it exists or use the get_or_create() method. [link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: ok. That's what I needed. I'm running get with try and except and that's the way to find out if the object was created or not. Thought there are some simpler way to do it. Thanks.